# Before vs. Until in this sentence

Tags: prepositions, difference

To some extent I know the difference between "before" and "until" as it is in [until VS. before](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46234/until-vs-before)

I wrote:

> For any given word, the program records the user’s choices during the test. It records the letters that they try **before entering** the correct letter.

If I want to use "until", can I just replace "before" or I must write it as:

> For any given word, the program records the user’s choices during the test. It records the letters that they try **until they enter** the correct letter.

Anyway, how can I use until in this sentence?

Comment: "before entering", "before they enter", "until entering", and "until they enter" are all fine in this sentence. I would note that saying *entering* is a bit ambiguous, as it could be interpreted as referring to *it* (i.e., the program) instead of *they* (i.e. the user).

Comment: *before entering* seems to refer to a series of events, while *until they enter* seems to refer to points in time.

Comment: Neither is clear.  Does it stop recording after the first accurate keystroke? Probably not.  If I spelled "cat"  k-c-a-d-t  it probably records both the "k" and the "d". Is that right?  So why not simply "The software records all incorrect keystrokes **as** the user attempts to spell a word."

Comment: @TRomano you are right, it records both "k" and "d". Maybe I should say "*before entering **a**  letter*" or "*before entering **each** letter*". The program saves them so that the relation between the failed attempts for each letter is recoverable. like (k)ca(d)t, where `k` is tried before `c` and `d` before `t`.

Comment: Those participles would be considered "dangling".  The program isn't doing the entering.  I think you could find a simpler way:  The program captures keystrokes **as** the user is spelling a word, so that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you may use ***until*** in place of *before* without changing the rest of the sentence.

TRomano's and Era's comments are correct, though, in that this still leaves the statement ambiguous. If you wanted to be explicit, I might suggest the following edits (in ***bold italic***).

> For ***every*** given word, the program records ***all user input*** during the test; thus it records ***all*** letters that they try ***until*** entering ***each*** correct letter.

This also makes the use of ***until*** a much better choice than before, as *until* points toward the interval of time that abruptly ends with each "correct letter."

Comment: I hope this is what you were looking for, Ahmad. If not, further clarification would allow further assistance.