# Until/till gerund? Grammar

Tags: grammar, word-usage

My English speaker friends said I can't say:

> I have 1 hour left **until/till** going home.

My friends recommended to use this:

> I have 1 hour left until/ till I go home.

But I can say this, right?

> I have 1 hour left **before** going home

Then even though in sentence 1 and 3, **until** and **before** are both prepositions, why can't I use gerund behind until and till?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think they are both equally correct. Maybe the sentence with "before" is more preferred, but I cannot see anything wrong using until".

The difference of meaning in the two sentences is the difference of meaning between "until" and "before".

Link provided by @Emma in the comments should help:

[until VS. before](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46234/until-vs-before)

NOTE: using "till" is not wrong, but it is very informal.